# Last Sale Date and Next Sale Date through data.table grouped by Name

Tags: r, data.table

Here is what my dataframe looks like:

```
df <- read.table(text='

Name      ActivityType      ActivityDate      LastSaleDate    NextSaleDate     
John       Email            1/1/2014             NA              2/1/2014
John       Sale             2/1/2014             NA              3/1/2014
John       Sale             3/1/2014             2/1/2014        NA        
John       Seminar          4/1/2014             3/1/2014        NA  
John       Webinar          5/1/2014             3/1/2014        NA  
Tom        Email            1/1/2014             NA              2/1/2015
Tom        Sale             2/1/2015             NA              3/1/2015
Tom        Sale             3/1/2015             2/1/2015        NA  
Tom        Seminar          4/1/2015             3/1/2015        NA  
Tom        Webinar          5/1/2015             3/1/2015        NA
                                                                      ', header=T)
```

I am trying to derive the two rightmost columns through data.table.I am looking at where ActivityType=Sale and finding the prior and next corresponding activity date for that **sale** activity type. A related dplyr solution would be

```
library(dplyr)
require(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(LastSaleDate=na.locf(lag(ifelse(ActivityType=="Sale",ActivityDate,NA)),na.rm=FALSE))
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the logic to create those columns? And what attempt have you made to solve this yourself?

Comment: Through the help of R community, I got the solution in dplyr as custlife %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(lastsale=na.locf(lag(ifelse(ActivityType=="Sale",ActivityDate,NA)),na.rm=FALSE)). I tried to use the shift function in data.table to no avail

Comment: Edit those details into your question, give some explanation of what that code is actually doing, and make a note that you're trying to adapt that `dplyr` code to `data.table`. Being as specific as you can be will help people come up with answers to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, but is quite a jumble:

```
DT[,c("LastSaleDate", "NextSaleDate") := {
  w   = which(ActivityType=="Sale")
  lst = rep(c(NA, w ), diff(c(0, w, .N  )) )
  nxt = rep(c(w , NA), diff(c(1, w, .N+1)) )
  list(ActivityDate[lst], ActivityDate[nxt])
}, by=Name]


    Name ActivityType ActivityDate LastSaleDate NextSaleDate
 1: John        Email     1/1/2014           NA     2/1/2014
 2: John         Sale     2/1/2014           NA     3/1/2014
 3: John         Sale     3/1/2014     2/1/2014           NA
 4: John      Seminar     4/1/2014     3/1/2014           NA
 5: John      Webinar     5/1/2014     3/1/2014           NA
 6:  Tom        Email     1/1/2014           NA     2/1/2015
 7:  Tom         Sale     2/1/2015           NA     3/1/2015
 8:  Tom         Sale     3/1/2015     2/1/2015           NA
 9:  Tom      Seminar     4/1/2015     3/1/2015           NA
10:  Tom      Webinar     5/1/2015     3/1/2015           NA
```

Answer (score 3):

I will use `library(data.table)`. First of let us remove two rightmost columns and convert `ActivityDate` to `Date` class.

```
dt <- as.data.table(read.table(text='

Name      ActivityType      ActivityDate      LastSaleDate    NextSaleDate     
John       Email            1/1/2014             NA              2/1/2014
John       Sale             2/1/2014             NA              3/1/2014
John       Sale             3/1/2014             2/1/2014        NA        
John       Seminar          4/1/2014             3/1/2014        NA  
John       Webinar          5/1/2014             3/1/2014        NA  
Tom        Email            1/1/2014             NA              2/1/2015
Tom        Sale             2/1/2015             NA              3/1/2015
Tom        Sale             3/1/2015             2/1/2015        NA  
Tom        Seminar          4/1/2015             3/1/2015        NA  
Tom        Webinar          5/1/2015             3/1/2015        NA
                                                                      ', header=T))

dt[, c('ActivityDate', 'LastSaleDate', 'NextSaleDate') := list(as.Date(ActivityDate, format = '%d/%m/%Y'), NULL, NULL)]
```

Next merge data on sales data to get all possible combinations and compute difference of days between any activity and sales activity:

```
setkeyv(dt, 'Name')
dt2 <- dt[dt[ActivityType == 'Sale'], allow.cartesian = TRUE]
dt2[, DateDiff := as.numeric(ActivityDate - i.ActivityDate)]
```

to obtain:

```
    Name ActivityType ActivityDate i.ActivityType i.ActivityDate DateDiff
 1: John        Email   2014-01-01           Sale     2014-01-02       -1
 2: John         Sale   2014-01-02           Sale     2014-01-02        0
 3: John         Sale   2014-01-03           Sale     2014-01-02        1
 4: John      Seminar   2014-01-04           Sale     2014-01-02        2
 5: John      Webinar   2014-01-05           Sale     2014-01-02        3
 6: John        Email   2014-01-01           Sale     2014-01-03       -2
 7: John         Sale   2014-01-02           Sale     2014-01-03       -1
 8: John         Sale   2014-01-03           Sale     2014-01-03        0
 9: John      Seminar   2014-01-04           Sale     2014-01-03        1
10: John      Webinar   2014-01-05           Sale     2014-01-03        2
11:  Tom        Email   2014-01-01           Sale     2015-01-02     -366
12:  Tom         Sale   2015-01-02           Sale     2015-01-02        0
13:  Tom         Sale   2015-01-03           Sale     2015-01-02        1
14:  Tom      Seminar   2015-01-04           Sale     2015-01-02        2
15:  Tom      Webinar   2015-01-05           Sale     2015-01-02        3
16:  Tom        Email   2014-01-01           Sale     2015-01-03     -367
17:  Tom         Sale   2015-01-02           Sale     2015-01-03       -1
18:  Tom         Sale   2015-01-03           Sale     2015-01-03        0
19:  Tom      Seminar   2015-01-04           Sale     2015-01-03        1
20:  Tom      Webinar   2015-01-05           Sale     2015-01-03        2
```

Now when you sort `dt2 <- dt2[order(Name, ActivityDate, DateDiff)]` you can obtain last and next sales dates by:

```
dt2[, list(ActivityType = ActivityType[1],
           LastSaleDate = head(i.ActivityDate[DateDiff > 0], 1),
           NextSaleDate = tail(i.ActivityDate[DateDiff < 0], 1)),
     by = list(Name, ActivityDate)]
```

Comment: Fyi, you can use `setDT` to modify a data.frame into a data.table in place instead of coercing with `as.data.table`; and `setorder` to sort in place, instead of overwriting like `dt2 <- dt2[order(...)]`. Also, it looks like you are relying upon there being at most one activity per Name and ActivityDate ... ?